# Join hashes which share a common key

Tags: perl, hashcode

I have two data files that have codes associated with named objects. The first file is a very long reference list containing all named objects and their associated code A and code B. The second file is a shorter list of items that are useful to me. I only have code A with the named items in this file. I would like to create a new file that has both codes for the objects of my interest.

datafile1:

```
12  apple   18
62  orange  26
114 banana  8
```

datafile2:

```
12  apple
62  orange
114 banana
```

I am a new programmer. The following is what I have tried. I get no matches and an empty output file.

```
open( INF, 'data.txt' );
my @array = <INF>;
my %codes;
our $Sep = "\t";

foreach my $line (@array) {
    chomp $line;
    my @temp = split /\t/, $line;
    my ($A_ID) = ( split( $Sep, $line ) )[0];
    push @{ $codes{$A_ID} }, $line;
}
close INF;

my %match;
open( IN, 'data2.txt' );
my @array_next = <IN>;
foreach my $line (@array_next) {
    chomp $line;
    ( my $bA_ID, my $name ) = split /\t/, $line;
    foreach my $codes_line ( @{ $codes{$A_ID} } ) {
        my ( $Name, $B_ID ) = ( split( $Sep, $line ) )[ 1, 2 ];
        my $new_array;
        if ( $bA_ID eq $A_ID ) {
            $new_array = $bA_ID . "\t" . $B_ID . "\t" . $Name;
            $match{new_array}++;
        }
    }
}

close IN;
print "Number of matched : " . keys(%match) . "\n";
open( OUT, ">Code_Match.txt" );
print OUT "$key\n";
```

Comment: Make sure you `use strict` and `use warnings` first

Comment: What is "unique" about the first file?  Will there be only one 'apple', etc?  Or, is it the combination of Code A and the object (apple, etc.) that are unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a clean up of your code. There are cleaner ways of doing this. Once you start using `use strict` and `use warnings` many, if not all, of your issues will disappear.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $INF, '<', 'data.txt');
my %codes;
my $Sep = qr/\t/;

while( my $line = <$INF>){
  chomp $line;
  my $A_ID = (split($Sep, $line ))[0]; 
  push @{$codes{$A_ID}},$line ; 
}
close $INF;

my %match;
open (my $IN, '<', 'data2.txt');
while( my $line = <$IN>){
  chomp $line;
  my ($bA_ID, $name) = split $Sep, $line;
  if (exists($codes{$bA_ID})) {
    foreach my $codes_line (@{$codes{$bA_ID}}) {
      my ($Name,$B_ID) = (split($Sep, $codes_line))[1,2];
      my $new_array = join("\t", $bA_ID, $B_ID, $Name);
      $match{$new_array}++;
    }
  }
}

close $IN;
print "Number of matched : ".keys(%match)."\n";
open (my $OUT,">", "Code_Match.txt");
print $OUT "$_\n" foreach keys(%match);
close $OUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

@imran beat me to it, but here was my attempt at cleaning up the code.  As he mentioned, use strict and warnings, but I also recommend a cleaner naming of variables.

For what it's worth, here's my cleaned-up code:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (IN, 'data.txt') or die $!;
my %codes;
my $Sep = "\t";
my $A_ID, my $B_ID;

while (<IN>){
  chomp;
  my $codeA1 = (split(/$Sep/, $_))[0];
  push(@{$codes{$codeA1}}, $_);
}
close(IN);
my %match;
open (IN, 'data2.txt') or die $!;
while(<IN>){
  chomp;
  my @fields = split(/$Sep/, $_);
  my $codeA2 = $fields[0];
  my $name2 = $fields[1];
  if (exists $codes{$codeA2}) {
    foreach (@{$codes{$codeA2}}) {
      $match{$_}++;
    }
  }
}
close(IN);

print "Number of matched : ". scalar(keys(%match)) ."\n";
open (OUT,">Code_Match.txt");
foreach (keys %match) {
  print OUT "$_\n";  
}
close(OUT);
```